# Facing an issue using react-native-snap-carousel. Is there a way to make swipe paginates/skips to next item, not dependent on the finger swipe speed?

Tags: react-native

I am using "react-native-snap-carousel": "4.0.0-beta.6".

There are some issues in android :-

Snap always works perfectly. Issues are following:

1. A medium finger swipe skips to 2 items later, instead of next item
2. A very light finger swipe skips to next item
   3)A hard finger swipe skips over ~ 4 items

Is there a way to lock it so it always paginates/skips to next item, not dependent on the finger swipe speed? Here is the code I am using for my Carousel

```
            <Carousel
              ref={slider1Ref}
              data={onBoardingCopy}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              sliderWidth={Math.round(screenWidth)}
              itemWidth={Math.round(screenWidth)}
              sliderHeight={screenHeight}
              inactiveSlideScale={1}
              onSnapToItem={(index: number) => {
                setActiveSlide(index);
              }}
              autoplay={true}
              autoplayDelay={500}
              autoplayInterval={6000}
              loop={true}
              loopClonesPerSide={4}
              enableSnap={true}
            />
```